# Is posible to display html & css formatted static content in JasperReports?

Tags: jasper-reports

I want to combine dynamically generated tables with a human created content formatted in html in the same document. The ultimate target will probably be PDF. The human generated content will generally consist of formatted text, tables and images. The formatting and layout requirements are generally fairly simple. This content will be specified in html, styled with css. The content itself will static in nature in that it will not be generated from data, but it could be sourced from files or a database. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Static text and Text field element support html syntax (you just have to chose it in properties), but you have to use in line style formatting. Something like:

```
<span style="color: #999">Some gray text</span><span style="color: #000"> black text</span>
```